# Unable to sum double digit numbers in this React code, it only sums 1 digit number

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to sum double-digit numbers in this React code. I can only sum single-digit numbers separated by a comma, like `1,2,3,4,5`. However, if I enter a double-digit number separated by a comma, I am unable to add it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Palindrome = () => {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");
  const [userOutput, setuserOutput] = useState([]);

  const inputted = (number) => {
    const array = number.split(",");
    const sum = array.reduce((a, b) => (a += b));
    var convert = Array.from(String(sum), (num) => Number(num));
    const sum1 = convert.reduce((a, b) => (a += b));

    setuserOutput(sum1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="puzzleBox filterStringPB">
      <h4> Get the total of an array of</h4>
      <span className="puzzleText">Example: {JSON.stringify(names[0])}</span>
      <input
        className="inputLine"
        onChange={(e) => setUserInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        className="confirmationButton"
        onClick={() => inputted(userInput)}
      >
        {" "}
        Compute{" "}
      </button>
      <span className="resultsBox filterStringRB">
        check Result: {JSON.stringify(userOutput)}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Palindrome;
```

here is an example:

When I input `1,2,3,4` it will sum up to `10`, however, when I input `12,12` it will sum up to `6`.

I want to add any length of numbers separated by comma to be summed up.

Comment: Post an example of input, current output and expected output to explain the question better

Comment: i just edit it bro please reply

Comment: Its because of the split function. You are splitting 1,2 and 1,2 creating [1,2,1,2] array

Comment: @MikaelTenshio, since the input is string the initial reduce operation will convert "12,12" into a string "1212" and then when you convert this to array it would become [1,2,1,2] . So you will need to convert input to number and then apply reduce.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert your string array to number when you use reduce function it will only allow numerical data.

Replace your `inputted` function with below code

```
const inputted = (number) => {
    const array = number.split(',').map(Number);    
    setuserOutput(array.reduce((pv, cv) => pv + cv, 0));
  };
```